# Laravel 5.4 | Custom Page for NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to redirect the user to a custom 404 page in case of NotFoundHttpException in Laravel 5.4

To do so, I added following piece of code in App\Exceptions\Handler.php file:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Not Found'], 404);
        }
        return response()->view('404', [], 404);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

For some reason this doesn't work. Can someone please point if I am doing something wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Hava you used the correct namespace `use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;`?

Comment: @Williamwei - Thanks a ton. I completely forgot to include it.

Answer (score 15):

Laravel will render your error pages before falling back on the default view.

If your view is created in: `resources/views/errors/404.blade.php`. This page will be rendered before the fallback error page.

The views in the above directory should have the names of the HTTP status code which you are trying to render.

More information can be found in the laravel docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors#custom-http-error-pages

Answer (score 5):

Just create your view here

```
resources/views/errors/404.blade.php
```

Laravel will serve it automatically for you

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to modify the render function. Keep it like the original:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

All you have to do is just make the view:

> resources/views/errors/404.blade.php

Then add some contents to the file, for example:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
404
@endsection
```

Laravel takes care of the rest...

Comment: There are already two answers saying exactly the same. Instead of answering again, consider up voting those and/or adding additional information via comments.