Render the default Laravel 404 page in Laravel 11 when page is not found
in my laravel 10, I had a app\Exceptions\Handler.php class to render a json response when something try to access an invalid api endpoint or to render the default framework 404 page when something try to access a non-existent non-api page:
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;
use Throwable;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    protected $dontReport = [];

    protected $dontFlash = [
        'current_password',
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    public function register()
    {
        $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {});
    }

    public function render($request, Throwable $e)
    {
        if ($request->is('api/*')) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 404, 'message' => 'route_not_found'], 404);
        } else {
            return parent::render($request, $e);
        }
    }
}

I've updated the framework to laravel 11 and moved the excetions to bootstrap\app.php using the ->withExceptions() method:
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
        api: __DIR__ . '/../routes/api.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->api(append: [
            \App\Http\Middleware\ApiResponse::class
        ])
            ->alias([
                'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class
            ]);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        $exceptions->render(function (Throwable $e, \Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
            if ($request->is('api/*')) {               
                return response()->json(['error' => 404, 'message' => 'route_not_found'], 404);
            } else {
                abort(404);
            }
        });
    })
    ->create();

the thing is I wish to use something like the return parent::render($request, $e); from laravel 10, since it return the default 404 page of the framework. The abort(404) in laravel 11 return a generic 500 error with no render at all.
I've tried to instantiate the Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler, but its constructor needs a container which I don't know how to provide one.
How can I render the default 404 error page in laravel 11 using the ->withExceptions() method?
thx in advance

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70932661/make-all-error-status-codes-return-a-single-custom-view might actually be of help of you.

Also checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42684854/laravel-5-4-custom-page-for-notfoundhttpexception/42971356#42971356

You can just leave off the else test, and not return/do anything in that case, you'll get a normal 404.  Did you find any other option?

This also works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78580554/laravel-11-custom-error-page-handling-problem
