Laravel 11 custom error page handling problem
I am using Laravel 11 and I want to error handling. I was did in Laravel 10 in app/Exceptions/Handler.php. However there is no handler.php in Laravel 11. How can I create separate custom error pages. For example admin panel have different 404 page from customer 404 page.
I was did in Laravel 10 in this style:
        if ($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException) {
            if ($request->is(['admin', 'admin/*'])) {
                if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 400) {
                    return response()->view("admin.errors.400", [], 400);
                }

                if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 403) {
                    return response()->view("admin.errors.403", [], 403);
                }

                if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {
                    return response()->view("admin.errors.404", [], 404);
                }

                if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 500) {
                    return response()->view("admin.errors.500", [], 500);
                }

                if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 503) {
                    return response()->view("admin.errors.503", [], 503);
                }
            }

            if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {
                return response()->view("customer.errors.404", [], 404);
            }
        }


Apparently it's been moved to bootstrap/app.php.

Laravel 11 'slimmed' down the application and moved a lot of the boilerplate to the framework code. Due to this, a lot of the files were removed, one of which is the ExceptionHandler class.
But it's still fully possible to customize how expections are rendered by modifying the bootstrap/app.php file.
Full documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/errors#rendering-exceptions
If you check the bootstrap/app.php file, you will notice
->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
    //
})

This is where your expection handling code will go.
To handle the NotFoundException, you would do
use \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;

// rest of the code

->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
    $exceptions->render(function (HttpException $exception, Request $request) {
        if ($request->is(['admin', 'admin/*'])) {
            if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 400) {
                return response()->view("admin.errors.400", [], 400);
            }

            if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 403) {
                return response()->view("admin.errors.403", [], 403);
            }

            if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {
                return response()->view("admin.errors.404", [], 404);
            }

            if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 500) {
                return response()->view("admin.errors.500", [], 500);
            }

            if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 503) {
                return response()->view("admin.errors.503", [], 503);
            }
        }

        if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {
            return response()->view("customer.errors.404", [], 404);
        }
    });
})


here, only the 404 view is being called. The others is showing the error pagings of navigator same

You're right, it's because of this line $exceptions->render(function (NotFoundHttpException $exception, Request $request) {, particularly the NotFoundHttpException. Changed it to HttpException which is the base exception for HTTP errors
